# CMake -> nmake: resulting build does not seem to know about WIN32 or WIN16

Tags: cmake, nmake

I am using CMake to build a piece of 3rd party software, which supplied the CMakeLists file.  I am using the generator "NMake Makefiles", which I would presume would include a definition of WIN32 or WIN64, but the signs are that the complier is being invoked without those macros defined.  If I were generating for Visual Studio, I would expect this to be implicit.  What is the correct course to make sure the symbol is defined when the compiler is invoked?  Is this normally defined with a platform detection in CMake?  Is this a possible omission from the original author?  Should I be defining one of these on the command line?

Comment: Are you compiling a C/C++ application or library? Do you mean that `WIN32` should be defined as a compile definition?

Comment: I am compiling a library.  The problem cropped up when POSIX headers were not found during the build.  The source was watching with preprocessors for WIN32 or WIN64 to select the appropriate headers.

Comment: It appears to be defined in the `flags.make` file when using NMake as the CMake generator. Can you verify you have this `flags.make` file in your CMake binary directory? Can you see what flags are defined there?